# Is there a practical limit to the number of files in a Swift container?

Tags: openstack

(Copied over from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65816607/197371) as I was told it is more appropriate here)

A solution I work on stores files in OpenStack's Swift but the files are spread out into multiple containers. I have been told this is because the performance is awful after about a million files in a container. The only reference I could find is from a blog of 2010
[http://adrianotto.com/2010/09/openstack-os-is-great-for/](https://web.archive.org/web/20161008022640/http://adrianotto.com/2010/09/openstack-os-is-great-for/).

Since

1. I cannot find any other documentation about such a limitation/performance issue
2. It has been more than 10 years since the blog post

Is there **still** a limitation (or performance issue) to the number of objects in object storage in recent versions of OpenStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also copying over my answer from Stackoverflow.

The page that documents Swift's relatively new [container sharding feature](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_container_sharding.html) makes that point as well. The fact that developers implemented this feature indicates that this is a real problem.

Container sharding could be a better method for your use case than storing objects in several containers, but it is still marked as experimental.